# Actionscript 3: Delete code-generated movieclips when changing frame

Tags: actionscript-3, frame, movieclip, removechild

This code generates airport symbol as a part of a bigger presentation. That works pretty  well, but at the moment the objects don't disappear when I change frame, which I would like them to.

I've tried different methods in the other frame, but whatever I do i get the error: "Call to a possibly undefined method removeChild through a reference with static type Class."

I'm pretty new to AS3, so keep that in mind :)

Thank you. Below is my code.

```
for (var key:Object in Airports) 
{
var MyAirport = new airport();
MyAirport.x = Airports[key]["x"];
MyAirport.y = Airports[key]["y"];
MyAirport.width = 17;
MyAirport.height = 17;
addChild(MyAirport)
MyAirport.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.clickHandler)
 }
```

Comment: Two questions. What is MyAirport being added to? Can we see the code used to remove it?

Comment: Not sure what it is added to, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your movieclips for each scene into an array as you build each scene.  Then you can loop through that array and remove them by calling a cleanup function:

```
function cleanupView():void
{
    for( var i:int = 0; i < collectedMovieClipsArray; i++ )
    {
        var parentContainer:MovieClip = collectedMovieClipsArray[ i ].parent as MovieClip;
        parentContainer.removeChild( collectedMovieClipsArray[ i ] );
    }
}
```

the **as MovieClip** part my not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. However I chose a simple path by using the following line:

```
this.parent.visible = false
```

This is hiding all the MovieClips
I will try to implement your code, though.